# Login Screen Android: Switching default activity

Tags: android

I have an application which uses Login. I want run this activity only if the user has not previously logged on. But this is my default activity. Is there a method to skip the default activity and go to the next activity directly?

Comment: Splash screen are use in your app?

Comment: No, I am not using a splash screen. My default activity is the login activity. @cyberlobe

Answer (score 6):

You should call, from your Login Activity, the next Activity (e.g. Profile) for it purpose. The app workflow is:

```
1. Start Login Activity (by default);
2. Check login state;
3. If user already logged - start new Activity and close this.
```

How to do that?

To call new Activity you should use Intent. To close current, so user can't go back to the Login Activity later, you should clear current app backstack (i.e activity history). Also, you can reset transition animation, so user (if logged) not even notice that Login Activity was called.

```
private void startProfileActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //clear backstack
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION); //it will looks like the transition inside the app, so user will not notice login activity, instead of default animation, which look like starting other app.
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How do I clear the current app backstack? (I am new to android programming)

Comment: I have updated my code. To clear backstack, you should add the flags to intent.
`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //clear backstack`

Answer (score 3):

You can use sharedpreferences for this purpose

**1. On Login (success)**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
          "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("isLogin", true).apply();
```

Now Switch your activity

**2. On next opening of the app, check**

```
if(prefs.getLong("isLogin", false)){
     //User already Login
}else{
     // User not logged in
}
```

P.S. you can use this check on `onStart()` of your LoginActivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This type Code:-


public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(islogin){      //your boolean variable
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(LoginActivity.this, "Your Next activity";
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```